# Value de button nao esta aparecendo

Tags: html, html5

[image][image][image]

ja testei no chrome e no firefox mas nada e nem a ide esta acusando acusando erro

Comment: Niko se fosse input daria certo para button a syntaxe é assim `<button type="button">Tecle Enter</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erro de sintaxe.
O correto seria:

- `<button>tecle enter</button>`

  ou
- `<input type="button" value="tecle enter"/>`